# Groovy AST superclass methods return null

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a super-class with CRUD methods like:

```
class CRUDController<T extends MongoEntity> implements ControllerTrait {
    
  @Transactional
  void list( RoutingContext rc ) {
    def q = query rc    
    def list = clazz.collection.find q collect{ it.asType clazz }
    ok rc, [ list:list, count:clazz.collection.count( q ) ]
  }
}
```

and multiple child-classes like:

```
@Grant( [ Permission.admin ] )
class GameController extends CRUDController<Game> {
  
  @Override
  void list( RoutingContext rc ) {
    super.list( rc )
  }
}

@Grant( [ Permission.admin ] )
class AppScriptController extends CRUDController<AppScript> {
  // no overrides
}
```

The `@Grant` is used to trigger the AST-Transformation:

```
@Retention( RUNTIME )
@Target( [ TYPE, METHOD ] )
@GroovyASTTransformationClass( classes = [ GrantASTTransformation ] )
@interface Grant {
  Permission[] value() default []
}
```

The AST:

```
@GroovyASTTransformation( phase = CANONICALIZATION )
@CompileStatic
class GrantASTTransformation implements ASTTransformation {
  
  @Override
  void visit( ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit source ) {
    if( !nodes ) return
    
    ClassNode classNode = (ClassNode) nodes.find{ it in ClassNode }
    
    if( classNode ) augmentClass classNode
  }

  private void augmentClass( ClassNode classNode ) {
    List<AnnotationNode> annos = classNode.getAnnotations new ClassNode( Grant )
    if( !annos ) return
    
    Expression rolesValue = annos.first().getMember 'value'

    List<MethodNode> methods = classNode.methods.findAll this.&matchesMethod
    Number count = methods.count this.&augmentMethod.rcurry( rolesValue )
    
    List<MethodNode> superMethods = classNode.superClass.methods.findAll{ !methods*.name.contains( it.name ) && matchesMethod( it ) }
    println "super $classNode.nameWithoutPackage -> ${superMethods*.name}"
    if( methods ) {
      println ''
      println superMethods[0].name
      println superMethods[0].code.text
      println ''
    }
  }

  private boolean augmentMethod( MethodNode methodNode, Expression rolesValue = null ) {
    println "$methodNode.declaringClass.nameWithoutPackage / $methodNode.name -> ${methodNode.code.text}"
  }
}
```

With all above-mentioned, the declared methods of each annotated child-class are augmented just fine, so that the output of `augmentMethod()` looks like so:

```
GameController / list -> { super.list(rc) }
```

BUT the println's for the `superMethods` always have `return null` as a method body:

```
super AppScriptController -> [list, details, delete, save]

list
return null
```

so, no reasonable augmentation of the super methods is possible.

How to grab the actual code of super methods? What am I missing?